# list of figures keeps header in latex book

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using LaTeX `scrbook` class and I want to have a chapter in the frontmatter. This chapter has as a header "list of figure", which comes from the previous element I added, and I cannot find how to remove it.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter*{chapter zero}
\blindtext[6]

\mainmatter
\chapter{first chapter}

\end{document}
```

How can the header "list of figures" be removed from my "chapter zero"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: When I compile your example I get the List of figures in a separate page. "List of figures" is in page `iii` and chapter zero is in page `v`. Or you want to *compĺetely* remove the List of figures?

Comment: Try `\listoffigures\cleardoublepage\markboth{}{}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: I think the O.P. wants to remove the 'List of figures' occurence in the page  header of the chapter 0

Comment: @ChristianHupfer oooh, *that* List of figures... I haven't seen that one `:P`. Sorry. BTW, your suggestion works, post it as an answer.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: No worries. And it's a KOMA related question, I don't answer them.

Answer (score 2):

If there should be no header and ToC entry for this chapter you can use `\addchap*`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addchap*{chapter zero}% <- changed
\blindtext[6]
\mainmatter
\chapter{first chapter}
\end{document}
```

---

If there should be "chapter zero" in the header of the second page of this chapter, but no entry in ToC, you could use

```
\documentclass[12pt,headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter[tocentry={}]{chapter zero}
\blindtext[6]
\mainmatter
\chapter{first chapter}
\end{document}
```

Note that chapters in frontmatter are unnumbered by default. If you need a similar chapter in mainmatter you have to use `\addchap` instead `\chapter`.